# Need assistance with a CSS grid

Tags: css

Found this grid online! And i've been trying to implement it into my code. However, I can't figure out the css, It's a total mess.

Need some help decrypting it, into traditional CSS? **Like with braces? { }**

```
$color: #ebeced
$gray: #dddddd

*
    box-sizing: border-box
    &:before, &:after
        box-sizing: border-box

=small
    @media only screen and (max-width: 766px)
        @content

=foo
    +small
        width: 100%

.row
    width: 100%
    max-width: 1020px
    margin: 0 auto
    clear:both
    overflow: hidden
    padding-top: 50px

    +small
        padding: 0 10px


%flok
    min-height: 10px
    margin: 1.0416666666666665%
    float: left
    overflow: hidden
    // background: $color
    border: 4px solid $gray

    +small
        margin-left: 0
        margin-right: 0


=col1 
    width: 6.25%
    @extend %flok
    +foo

=col2
    width: 14.583333333333334%
    @extend %flok
    +foo

=col3
    width: 22.916666666666664%
    @extend %flok
    +foo

=col4
    width: 31.25%
    @extend %flok
    +foo

=col5
    width: 39.58333333333333%
    @extend %flok
    +foo

=col6
    width: 47.91666666666667%
    @extend %flok
    +foo

=col7
    width: 56.25%
    @extend %flok
    +foo

=col8
    width: 64.58333333333334%
    @extend %flok
    +foo

=col9
    width: 72.91666666666666%
    @extend %flok
    +foo

=col10
    width: 81.25%
    @extend %flok
    +foo

=col11
    width: 89.58333333333334%
    @extend %flok
    +foo

=col12
    width: 97.91666666666666%
    @extend %flok
    +foo

// decorate
body
    text-align: center
    line-height: 2.5
    margin: 0
    padding: 0
    color: darken($gray, 10%)
    font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif'
    font-weight: 300

h1
    text-align: center
    font-size: 45px
    line-height: 1.2
    padding: 45px 0 0
    color: darken($gray, 20%)

.colon1
    +col1

.colon2
    +col2

.colon3
    +col3

.colon4
    +col4

.colon5
    +col5

.colon6
    +col6

.colon7
    +col7

.colon8
    +col8

.colon9
    +col9

.colon10
    +col10

.colon11
    +col11

.colon12
    +col12
```

[**URL to CSSDeck**](http://cssdeck.com/labs/sexy-grid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to the demo and click the wrench in the top left, you will see that is not exactly CSS, it is [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/), a CSS compiling language. Sass makes it easier for the programmer to write CSS, especially loops of similar things like the example you posted shows

To see the actual CSS, click the `(!)` button at the top of the SASS, which will provide the following

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1020px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
    .row {
        padding: 0 10px;
    }
}
.colon1, .colon2, .colon3, .colon4, .colon5, .colon6, .colon7, .colon8, .colon9, .colon10, .colon11, .colon12 {
    min-height: 10px;
    margin: 1.04167%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 4px solid #dddddd;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
    .colon1, .colon2, .colon3, .colon4, .colon5, .colon6, .colon7, .colon8, .colon9, .colon10, .colon11, .colon12 {
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
body {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2.5;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #c4c4c4;
    font-family:"Open Sans", "sans-serif";
    font-weight: 300;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 45px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    padding: 45px 0 0;
    color: #aaaaaa;
}
.colon1 {
    width: 6.25%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
    .colon1 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
.colon2 {
    width: 14.58333%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
    .colon2 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
.colon3 {
    width: 22.91667%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
    .colon3 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
.colon4 {
    width: 31.25%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
    .colon4 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
.colon5 {
    width: 39.58333%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
    .colon5 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
.colon6 {
    width: 47.91667%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
    .colon6 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
.colon7 {
    width: 56.25%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
    .colon7 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
.colon8 {
    width: 64.58333%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
    .colon8 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
.colon9 {
    width: 72.91667%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
    .colon9 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
.colon10 {
    width: 81.25%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
    .colon10 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
.colon11 {
    width: 89.58333%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
    .colon11 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
.colon12 {
    width: 97.91667%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
    .colon12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```